# Chrome table glitch when cells have rowspan and colspan

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, html-table

I've encountered a glitch while printing a table, which contains cells with `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes, using Google Chrome.
If you run the following snippet, the table is displayed normally.

```js
print();
```

```css
thead{background-color:#d3d3d3}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}th{border-bottom:1px solid #e6e6e6;border-left:1px solid #e6e6e6;font-size:12px;font-weight:700;text-align:center;padding:12px 12px}th:last-child{border-right:1px solid #e6e6e6}thead>tr:first-child{border-top:1px solid #e6e6e6}td{border-bottom:1px solid #e6e6e6;border-top:1px solid #e6e6e6;border-left:1px solid #e6e6e6;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;padding:8px 12px}td:last-child{border-right:1px solid #e6e6e6}tbody>tr:nth-child(3n+1){background:#ffe1c3}tbody>tr:nth-child(3n+2){background:#fff8d8}tbody>tr:nth-child(3n+3){background:#ffffea}
```

```html
<table> <thead> <tr> <th colspan="1" rowspan="2">Year</th> <th colspan="3" rowspan="1">Other</th> </tr> <tr> <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">A</th> <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">B</th> <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">C</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td rowspan="3">2000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1999</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1998</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1997</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1996</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1995</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">2000</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1999</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1998</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1997</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1996</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1995</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1994</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1993</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1992</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1991</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1990</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1989</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1988</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1987</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1986</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1985</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1984</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1983</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1982</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1981</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td rowspan="3">1980</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr> </tbody></table>
```

But if you try to print (Print Preview or convert to PDF) the table using `Google Chrome`, the table glitches. Please check the following outputs from Chome and Firefox respectively:

[image: Print Error]

Is this a bug? Is there a way to overcome it?

Comment: Have you tried page break avoid on the data table rows? Or on the row spanned cell?

Comment: @KevinBrown do you mean `@media print { selector {  page-break-after: always; } }`? If yes, then no because I dont know where to cut the table (could be landscape, could be portrait).

Comment: I think you have some `colspan` values wrong. Check the 1986 entry for instance. It seems that `colspan` should be `2`, not `3`, am I right?

Comment: @FonzTech do you mean `rowspan`? `colspan` is only on the title. If you mean `rowspan`, you can see that changing the `3` to `2` will break the table format.

Comment: I am using chrome and the table loads in just fine. Do you have the latest version of chrome, I am just curious. The top of the table is fine as well!
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g92dN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g92dN.png)

Comment: You have to print the page (or preview its printing) to see the bug the OP is questioning for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure sounds like chrome bug.

Have you considered using table-row-group?

```
thead { 
  display: table-row-group 
}
```

This will remove the repetition of table headers at page breaks.

Hope it helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Having the years in their  own `td` element is confusing because the browsers then don't break the table at the end of a page as expected. Since the year column spans two rows,  it won't break with the relevant cells, which are shorter.

So then here's the required changes to your code to make the table break properly when printed.

```js
print();
```

```css
thead {
  background-color: #d3d3d3
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}

th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 12px
}

th:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6
}

thead>tr:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6
}

td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 8px 12px
}

td:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6
}

tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #fff8d8
}

tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) :first-child {
  background: #ffe1c3
}

tbody>tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ffffea
}
```

```html
   <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1" rowspan="2">Year</th>
      <th colspan="3" rowspan="1">Other</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">A</th>
      <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">B</th>
      <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">2000</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1999</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1998</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1997</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1996</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1995</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">2000</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1999</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1998</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1997</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1996</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1995</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1994</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1993</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1992</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1991</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1990</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1989</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1988</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1987</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1986</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1985</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1984</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1983</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1982</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1981</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1980</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You completely changed the table. If there was an error with the format of the table I supplied, I would have no problem with this change, but since it's valid html and firefox has no issue printing the table, this doesn't answer my question.